# Minecraft multiple Mob data tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to spawn a slime with 1/2 a heart and it's the max size, but all I get is a randomly sized normal slime.

I am using this command:

```
/summon minecraft:slime {size:4,Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:1}]}
```

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the wiki on [slime data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime#Data_values).  Maximum size is 3 naturally.  Size has to be capitalized in data tag and Health can be used as well.

Here is the command:

```
/summon slime ~ ~ ~ {Health:1,Size:3}
```

---

Edit: Response to comment

I played with Attributes to set maxHealth but it did not appear to work.  After your comment I did some research.

I found [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/351954-how-to-give-mobs-custom-health-with-summon?comment=8) on a forum which talked about how Size tag overrides the Attributes.  It also points to [MC-33285 bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-33285) which states that summoning slimes with maxHealth doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but the Health tag only sets the Health it is at when spawned, rather than max health, the reason I was using the more complex tag is because it is more efficient in giving the slime whatever health i wanted to, so I could give it 1000 hearts if I wanted, whereas health only goes up to the max health the mob naturally spawns with